# Efficient Implementation of join and split operations on semisplaying tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees, search-trees, splay-trees

[Splaying trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree) are a heavily researched of theoretical computer science as they are conjectured to be optimal binary trees. They were first presented by Sleator & Tarjan in [Self-Adjusting Binary Search Trees](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Esleator/papers/self-adjusting.pdf). In their paper, on pages 19-20, they propose to reduce the number of operations needed for a splay, by only doing some of the rotations and not all. This semisplaying method is more efficient and has [a noticeable better performance](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/spe.886). It is also one of the only [actual performance improvements](https://eapache.github.io/assets/Huus2014_SplayTrees.pdf) on different splaying methods proposed. Considering all this, I have decided to implement an semisplaying tree.

The access, insert and delete operations are the same and only require a little more attention to the splaying done. However, for the join and split operations, Sleator & Tarjan state that "the *join* and *split* algorithms become more complicated", which seems that this is the case, as the operations rely on the splaying to make the accessed node (for the joining/splitting) the root of the tree. This is not the case for semisplaying as the accessed node only goes halfway up the tree.

How should you implement the join/split operations for a semi-splaying tree efficiently?

I see two solutions to this. The first is that the regular full-splaying is used when joining/splitting to ensure that the accessed node is the root of the tree. The second is that the joining/splitting happens at the accessed node halfway up the tree. This decision may be important, as a wrong implementation led to a [paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/spe.394) stating that semisplaying is less efficient in practice.

Comment: The link http://caagt.ugent.be/preprints/splay_spe.pdf, appears to be broken

Comment: @Russel Fixed, I couldn't find a non-paywalled version of it